# Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted Aborted

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

I have the following program. I am getting this strange runtime error that doesn't make sense to me. I am linking with pthread. More text to get rid of annoying mostly code box.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

class OneTask
{
    std::promise<std::list<int> > resList;
public:
    void Execute(int x)
    {
        std::list<int> res;
        for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
        }

        resList.set_value(move(res));
    }

    std::future<std::list<int> > Result()
    {
        return resList.get_future();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "start" << "\n";

    OneTask ot;

    std::cout << "before fut=" << "\n";
    std::future<std::list<int> > fut = ot.Result();

    std::cout << "before creation of th" << "\n";
    std::thread th(&OneTask::Execute, &ot, 2);

    std::cout << "before fut.get" << "\n";
    std::list<int> res = fut.get();
    int r = res.size();
    std::cout << r << std::endl;

    std::cout << "before join" << "\n";

    th.join();

    while(1)
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get this:

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/STDPromiseFuture/bin/Release $ ./STDPromiseFuture 
start
before fut=
before creation of th
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Aborted
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/STDPromiseFuture/bin/Release $
```

This is the way it is compiled:

**EDIT**

```
g++ -Wall -pthread -O2 -std=c++11  -c /home/idf/Documents/STDPromiseFuture/STDPromiseFuture.cpp -o obj/Release/STDPromiseFuture.o
g++  -Wl,--no-as-needed -o bin/Release/STDPromiseFuture obj/Release/STDPromiseFuture.o  -s  -lpthread -lrt
Output file is bin/Release/STDPromiseFuture with size 18.53 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/STDPromiseFuture/bin/Release $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/STDPromiseFuture/bin/Release $
```

Comment: Try passing `-pthread` in compile and link steps.

Comment: See above under EDIT section. Made both changes. Still same problem

Comment: Ahh, that "-Wl,--no-as-needed" is a linker option. Now it works.